# Returning to main Activity causes Dropping event due to no window focus

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a MainActivity in which i have a many fragments which have different images on click of one of the images it goes to imageviewer activity which then shows image in a fullscreen view but the problem arises when i click on back button in imageviewer activity as it leads to main activity but mainactivity doesnt respond to any touch events even navigation drawer cant be opened

i go to the imageviewer activity with this code

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoZoomage=new Intent(getActivity(),ImageViewer2.class);
            gotoZoomage.putExtra("imageurl",mainurl);
            gotoZoomage.putExtra("fragment",0);
            gotoZoomage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getActivity().startActivity(gotoZoomage);
        }
    });
```

and on back pressed for imageviewer activity is as follows

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onBackPressed() try to remove finish(). Back should lead you back to the old activity.

And remove Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK . FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.